# Marshmallow fields.Nested(...,nullable=True)

Tags: python, marshmallow

I'm currently working on a legacy codebase that involves nested fields with the `nullable=True` parameter. In my review of the source code for Marshmallow version 3.21.1, I couldn't find any reference to this parameter. Is it possible that `nullable=True` is an outdated argument, and can I replace it with `allow_none=True?` Should I use it as `metadata`?

Comment: please provide code